# how to transfer big files using webservice api in wordpress or php

Tags: php, web-services, api, wordpress

Is there a way to transfer big files using webservice api in wordpress or php?

Comment: your question is too short. Add some more details like which webservice API and where do you want to transfer files from ?

Comment: wat i want to achieve is tat Client w'have library of wordpress themes calld wps themes on his server.
I need to create a plugin which when install 1)- The plugin w'l search for a wps themes,if d's not find any wps theme installed on the client server it w'l search and display all wps themes that are available and it w'l advise d user that api is required to activate the full functiality of theme. but if dont want to use api, user still can install any wps theme but in degrade mode(without plugins).2)- if he uses the api and then all the plug ins related to particular themes will be installed.

Comment: My main concern is here how to search the themes and how to copy the files from there? let me know if you still need more detail?

Comment: You can edit your question to include the description you had to summarize in your comment. If I understand it correctly you want to provide a catalog of themes, where a user can download and install a "lite" version for free, and a full version if a certain API is used (do you mean you give paying customers an API key?). Use `@Jan` in your reply to notify me, otherwise I won't see it.